# slow server on ssh output of top

Tags: ubuntu, stress-testing

```
top - 21:15:43 up  2:28,  1 user,  load average: 0.54, 0.50, 0.52
Tasks: 225 total,   1 running, 223 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.4%us,  2.9%sy,  0.0%ni, 96.5%id,  0.2%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   8181868k total,  4332744k used,  3849124k free,  1336596k buffers
Swap: 15624184k total,        0k used, 15624184k free,   169468k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                    
   85 root      25   5     0    0    0 S   17  0.0  28:57.08 ksmd                                                                                                       
 2457 root      20   0 1232m 922m 3404 S    3 11.6  14:37.69 kvm                                                                                                        
 2431 root      20   0 2270m 1.1g 3392 S    2 14.0   7:01.86 kvm                                                                                                        
 2344 root      20   0 1981m 324m 3392 S    1  4.1   0:46.49 kvm                                                                                                        
 3911 root      20   0 2249m 320m 3364 S    1  4.0   1:57.91 kvm                                                                                                        
10636 root      20   0 19332 1504 1056 R    0  0.0   0:00.07 top                                                                                                        
10871 root      20   0 54732 2472 1788 S    0  0.0   0:00.01 apache2                                                                                                    
    1 root      20   0 23944 2220 1292 S    0  0.0   0:14.87 init                                                                                                       
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.02 kthreadd                                                                                                   
    3 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.01 migration/0                                                                                                
    4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.10 ksoftirqd/0                                                                                                
    5 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/0                                                                                                 
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.01 migration/1                                                                                                
    7 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.51 ksoftirqd/1                                                                                                
    8 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/1                                                                                                 
    9 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.03 migration/2                                                                                                
   10 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.45 ksoftirqd/2                                                                                                
   11 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/2                                                                                                 
   12 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.01 migration/3                                                                                                
   13 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.81 ksoftirqd/3                                                                                                
   14 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/3                                                                                                 
   15 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.14 migration/4                                                                                                
   16 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.13 ksoftirqd/4                                                                                                
   17 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/4                                                                                                 
   18 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.15 migration/5                                                                                                
   19 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.15 ksoftirqd/5                                                                                                
   20 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/5                                                                                                 
   21 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.07 migration/6                                                                                                
   22 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.05 ksoftirqd/6                                                                                                
   23 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/6                                                                                                 
   24 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.19 migration/7                                                                                                
   25 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.29 ksoftirqd/7
```

Above is output of top on my server when I did a `top` and I found server responding very slow over key strokes.For example I typed `virt-manager` on command prompt and I could see that when I press any key the response came out after a significant delay.What can be reason for above and what should I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to test network by [iperf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf/). Also [test](http://www.speedtest.net/) your internet connection.

Comment: Do I need to install iperf on server or on my laptop.From my home I tested the internet connection speed on your link here is the result
http://www.speedtest.net/result/1136089460.png

Comment: You need to install iperf to laptop.